# A way to convert "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" into "-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4"

Tags: python, loops, math

I have this basic loop:

```
for x in range(1, len(testList) + 1)
        print(x, end=", ")
```

Let's say `testList` is a length of 9. Then, this will output `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`. The problem is, I want it to print out `-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. Could someone please tell me a way to do this?

**NOTE:** I can't just subtract by `5` or a constant as the length of `testList` changes.

Comment: What would you want if `testList` had a length of 10?

Comment: `-3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5` if the length is 10

Comment: That's only 9 values; did you mean to start at `-4.5`?

Comment: So you want to do x - (len(testList)+1)/2 ?

Comment: Yeah, @Nick, whoops

Comment: Can you clarify your question? That title should be far more descriptive.

Comment: @AMC, Could you give me an idea for a new title?

Comment: @AyushGarg Not really, considering that you’re the one who knows the most about the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if you want to adjust the starting point by something related to the length of the list, just use the length of the list to calculate the delta, something like:

```
for x in range(len(testList)):
    print(x - len(testList) // 2, end=", ")
```

You'll have to tidy that up for edge cases such as what to do if the list has an even number of elements, but that's still the same concept, using the length to work out how to change each element.

You should also realise that you get a closing separator with that code along with no newline at the end. See below for one fix to that.

It's only really meant as an example of how you can adjust the starting point.

---

Of course, you could always opt for the more Pythonic:

```
>>> print(", ".join([str(n - len(testList) // 2) for n in range(len(testList))]))
-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

although, if you're *beginning* with Python, that may not be such a good idea :-)

It's nice to know these things as you become more advanced but it's not necessarily conducive to learning the language to start with. The explanation below is really for new Python developers, feel free to ignore if you already understand list comprehensions.

It also has the advantage of not putting the separator after the final item and works as follows:

1. The `for` loop gives you the sequence of items `0..n-1`, where `n` is the list length.
2. The `n-len(x)//2` adjusts those to give you a range (roughly) centered around zero.
3. The `str()` turns those into strings.
4. The surrounding `[]` characters turn that whole sequence into a list.
5. The `join` joins those list items together with `", "` as the separator.

---

In terms of what to do if you want it centered *exactly* around zero with even or odd list length (as you've mentioned in a comment), the correct statement would be:

```
print(", ".join([str(n + 0.5 - len(testList) / 2) for n in range(len(testList))]))
```

You can confirm that with the following transcript:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     testList = [0] * i
...     print(i, ":", ", ".join([str(n + 0.5 - len(testList) / 2) for n in range(len(testList))]))
...
0 :
1 : 0.0
2 : -0.5, 0.5
3 : -1.0, 0.0, 1.0
4 : -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5
5 : -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0
6 : -2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5
7 : -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0
8 : -3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5
9 : -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
```

Comment: Actually, for the first example, you have to change it to `x - 1` because otherwise you would get one less number than usual.

Comment: The first example was really only intended to give an example on how to adjust based on the length. A more useful example is in the last stanza, where it starts at the correct value, including catering for half-integers where the list length is even.